# How to add scroll buttons in a zoomed image using interactive viewer widget and transformationController in flutter

Tags: flutter, controller, transformation, pinchzoom, pan

```
transformationController.value = Matrix4.identity()
        ..translate(-200.0, 0.0); // translate(x,y)
```

//tried like this and it just goes back to its original position . I need scroll functions in a zoomed image using 4 buttons(top,left,right,bottom) using InteractiveViewer widget and transformation controller